# Python3.5 claiming pip installations in virtualenv and its uninstallation causing errors

Tags: python3, pip, django, virtualenvwrapper

```
nmj@pc-nm:~$ sudo apt remove python3.5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 debconf : PreDepends: perl-base (>= 5.6.1-4) but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: apt-utils (>= 0.5.1) but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: debconf-i18n but it is not going to be installed
 init-system-helpers : Depends: perl-base (>= 5.20.1-3) but it is not going to be installed
 libacl1 : Depends: libattr1 (>= 1:2.4.46-8) but it is not going to be installed
 libedit2 : Depends: libtinfo5 (>= 6) but it is not going to be installed
 libsystemd0 : PreDepends: libgcrypt20 (>= 1.6.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libxml2 : Depends: libicu65 (>= 65.1-1~) but it is not going to be installed
 libzvbi0 : Depends: libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4) but it is not going to be installed
 procps : Depends: libncurses5 (>= 6) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libncursesw5 (>= 6) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libprocps4 but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libtinfo5 (>= 6) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: initscripts
 psmisc : Depends: libtinfo5 (>= 6) but it is not going to be installed
 systemd : PreDepends: libgcrypt20 (>= 1.6.1) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libaudit1 (>= 1:2.2.1) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libblkid1 (>= 2.19.1) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libcryptsetup4 (>= 2:1.4.3) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libmount1 (>= 2.26.2) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libpam0g (>= 0.99.7.1) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: util-linux (>= 2.27.1)
           Depends: mount (>= 2.26)
           Depends: adduser but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: libpam-systemd but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: dbus
 ucf : Depends: coreutils (>= 5.91)
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Above is my error log.
I am trying to uninstall python3.5 to retain python3.9 but i keep getting this error.
I need help guys
I use ubuntu 16.04LTS
And i'm trying to work on a django project but pip even inside a venv keeps parsing all its packages into the python3.5 base dir and this is getting so annoying because after hours of searching for fixes, i keep bumping into more errors because of this version conflict.

Then for the virtualenv, whenever i try to install django with `pip install django`, it cant install past version 2.1.0.
Yet i needed to install 3.1.7
I do have the django 3 version installed as root but in this particular virtualenv, i feel python3.5 is claming pip and all installations are just messy.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix for this.
It's very simple to create virtualenvs that are version specific

How?

```
virtualenv venv --python=python3.9
```

from above python 3.9 will be the only version therein

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

Now do comfirm your confliction free zone with the following

```
pip --version
pip3 --version
```

The 2 result in 1 answer

```
python --version
python3 --version
python3.9 --version
```

The above 3 result in 1 answer.

Now for installations from pip, you'd just do a `pip install ...`
`pip --freeze` will show you all requirements inside of the venv in qn

Hope this helps someone out there.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not quite clear to me from your description. But I have an idea, probably it may help you out.

How many versions of python have been installed in your system?

If you don't know it, try this,

```
find /usr /lib* /home -type d \( -name "*site-packages" -or -name "*dist-packages" \)
```

The idea is to find all the location for Python distribution and package folders.

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
/home/name/pyenv/versions/3.8.3/lib/python3.8/site-packages
```

Then you will have a clear sense what versions of Python have been compiled to your system.

Now, it's time to get all their `pip`s. (some of them may not have if you don't install it)

```
find /bin /usr /lib* /home -type f -name "pip*" -executable
```

You may get some outputs like;

```
/usr/bin/pip3
/usr/bin/pip3.5
/home/NAME/pyenv/shims/pip3
```

Test them one by one by using:

```
PATH-of-PIP --version

e.g.

/usr/bin/pip3 --version
```

To know where those `pip`s are linking to.

In your case, since you want to use version `python-3.9`, you can;

```
pip-full-path-for-3.9 install django
```

For convenience, you can also permanently add it to your `.bashrc` file. My suggestion is to add an `alias` to it. Or make a symbolic link. Or change its name for easy remember to use if you are really sure to it.

```
echo "alias pip3.9=pip-full-path-for-3.9" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Thank you man! I have 3 versions of python(2.7, 3.5, 3.9) each running its own pip version. So specifying pip3.9 which is the one that is affiliated to python 3.9 has resumed the progress on my end.

Comment: However 'echo "alias pip3.9=/usr/local/bin/pip3.9" >> ~/.bashrc'  creates an alias statement at the end of the .bashrc file in the form 'alias pip3.9=/usr/local/bin/pip3.9' and each time i try to use pip3.9 again in the terminal, I'm told that the specified path is a directory. So basically pip3.9 is working without the 'echo alias...' line in your answer. How can i improve it. because at least the progress is so far so good. Thanks again.

Comment: From your writing, "I'm told that the specified path is a directory." Your searched `pip` results cannot be directories, because we have specified the results should be the exetutable files. I probably know what your mean, you should run `. ~/.bashrc`, or re-open your current terminal, to make command take effects.

Comment: Now when i try doing a pip3.9 freeze inside a virtualenv, i get modules that are intalled globally. What could be the problem? Yet pip and pip3 only show me the modules in that virtualenv. But like i said before, the last 2 pips keep installing older versions of modules which i dont want.

Comment: If you use `pip` install package without specifying their versions, `pip` will help calculate the most preferable versions for your current Python setup environments, which is one of the reasons that makes it powerful and convenient. If you want to install the specific version, please take a look on this question [installing-specific-package-versions-with-pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226311/installing-specific-package-versions-with-pip)